# Using Handlebars.js, how do I populate a select box with global context data but set the selected item with data from the current loop item?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "Colours": [
        { "ColourID": 1, "Name": "Red" },
        { "ColourID": 2, "Name": "Yellow" },
        { "ColourID": 3, "Name": "Blue" }
    ],
    "Sizes": [
        { "SizeID": 1, "Name": "Small" },
        { "SizeID": 2, "Name": "Medium" },
        { "SizeID": 3, "Name": "Large" }
    ],
    "Products": [
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 1, "Name": "Red Small" },
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 2, "Name": "Red Medium" },
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 3, "Name": "Red Large" },
        // and so on...
    ]
}
```

And the following template HTML:

```
<table>
    {{#Products}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="{{Name}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Colours}}
                <option value="{{ColourID}}">{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Colours}}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Sizes}}
                <option value="{{SizeID}}">{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Sizes}}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/Products}}
</table>
```

How can I build the `select` boxes using the common colour/size data from the global context, but for each table row set the `selected="selected"` attribute on the options which have values matching the current product's Colour/Size ID?

As it stands, within the loop there is no access to the `Colours` or `Sizes` arrays, so the selects are blank. I've tried using a global helper to explicitly pass them into each product from the global context before rendering, like so:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('productloop', function(context, options) {
    var ret = [];

    for(var i=0, j=context.Products.length; i<j; i++) {
        var option = context.Products[i];

        option.Colours = context.Colours;
        option.Sizes = context.Sizes;

        ret.push(options.fn(option));
    }

    return ret.join('');
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<table>
    {{#productloop}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="{{Name}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Colours}}
                <option value="{{ColourID}}">{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Colours}}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Sizes}}
                <option value="{{SizeID}}">{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Sizes}}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/productloop}}
</table>
```

Which does work, but it seems very clunky, and I still have no idea how to set the `selected` attributes for each product's colour/size select.

Can anyone help me out? I have control over the code which generates the JSON, so the JSON structure can be changed if required.

Comment: Why doesn't your JSON have double quotes around the property names?

Comment: Because it was formatted that way by a Chrome extension I use and I just copied and pasted it in. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `../` to step up one level in the namespace:

```
<select>
    {{#each ../Colours}}
    <option value="{{ColourID}}">{{Name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I also switched to `{{#each}}` as I find it more readable when dealing with `../`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pFpS4/

Comment: Given the same dataset as the OP posted, what if this scenario was editing an existing order (for example), how would you perform a comparison to `select` a specific option?  `<option value="{{CoulourID}}" selected>{{Name}}</option>`?

Comment: @HPWD Haven't used Handlebars for several years but my usual solution with Handlebars was to do the heavy lifting in JavaScript (i.e. change the data) so that you wouldn't need to fancy logic in the templates.

Comment: I knew it was a long shot I'd get a reply due to the age of this post but thought I'd ask anyway. :) Thank you for replying. I ended up looping over the JSON data set in my controller and performing some logic there; I then added {{isSelected}} to my handlebars template with an #if_eq handlebar helper. It was far easier than I expected once I sat down with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Add selected property in your handlebar template for the current product .
Eg. for Blue, Small, Red medium...

```
{
    Colours: [
        { "ColourID": 1, "Name": "Red" },
        { "ColourID": 2, "Name": "Yellow" },
        { "ColourID": 3, "Name": "Blue", "selected" : "selected"  }
    ],
    Sizes: [
        { "SizeID": 1, "Name": "Small" , "selected" : "selected" },
        { "SizeID": 2, "Name": "Medium" },
        { "SizeID": 3, "Name": "Large" }
    ],
    Products: [
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 1, "Name": "Red Small" },
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 2, "Name": "Red Medium", "selected" : "selected" },
        { "ColourID": 1, "SizeID": 3, "Name": "Red Large" },
        // and so on...
    ]
}
```

And then use that inside your template like following.

```
<table>
    {{#Products}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="{{Name}}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Colours}}
                <option value="{{ColourID}}" {{selected}}>{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Colours}}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                {{#Sizes}}
                <option value="{{SizeID}}"  {{selected}}>{{Name}}</option>
                {{/Sizes}}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/Products}}
</table>
```

Comment: No, this won't work—the selected value will (or at least could) be different for every row, so I can't set selected properties on the global arrays.